# How to download and add the all attiny files to arduino ide

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, attiny

how to download and add the all attiny files to arduino ide. I want the files to program attiny2313a ic, Any specific links to download the attiny files, and the steps to download and install them in the arduino ide.......

Comment: The default/standard Arduinocore-avr core installed on the Arduino IDE does not support the ATtiny chip, you need to install the [ATtinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) to add the support for the ATtiny chip.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Boards Manager in the Arduino IDE.  I haven't used that particular processor in a while, but I think either ATTinyCore or MicroCore.   If you search for attiny you should get a few options in the boards manager.

Comment: you have to add the URL in Preferences to have a third party boards package in Boards Manager